# Random walk average meeting time

Tags: statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes

Imagine having a random walk of $N$ steps ($N$ is large, may be approximated to be infinity), but all the points are 1 unit length apart and they have to stay this unit length apart. Every timestep $\Delta t$, the points move at random a length $a$ (but they stay a unit length 1 apart). How long on average would it take for two points, separated by $n$ other points in the chain, to come less than or equal to a unit length apart? Can one calculate this analytically or approximate this in a clever way?